# Secure Chrome passwords against WebBrowserPassView

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, security

I just got shocked with what [WebBrowserPassView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_browser_password.html) can show - it basically shows every password I've saved in my browser (Chrome).

I guess other users on my PC could get my passwords that easily too. How do I secure myself?

Comment: Encrypt the passwords, limitation of the tool, says so right on the website

Comment: I have all data encrypted with sync passphrase in google chrome, even so is showing all my passwords.

Comment: "On Google Chrome - passwords originally imported from Internet Explorer 7.0-9.0, cannot be decrypted." - Sounds like that applies to your situation

Comment: "...cannot be decrypted" should mean passwords would not be shown, right? Anyway, I didn't imported anything from that IE.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome "protects" your saved passwords with the Windows [DPAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) (Data Protection API). The DPAPI has two encryption modes, or scopes: user and machine.

Data protected in the machine scope is encrypted with a per-machine key. Every authenticated user on the machine can use the DPAPI to unprotect such data, no matter which user originally protected it.

Data protected in the user scope is encrypted with a per-user key. That key is protected by a different key derived from your Windows password. (That's unrelated to the fact that Chrome requires you to enter your Windows password to view its saved passwords, though.) Fortunately, Chrome uses this mode.

An interesting consequence of the per-user DPAPI key encryption is that protected data cannot be decrypted by other users on the machine, even by administrators, because they can only get a hash of your password, not the original. (That doesn't stop them from installing keyloggers or other spy programs that run as you, of course.) If your Windows password is forcibly reset - not gracefully changed - data protected in your scope will be, in essence, destroyed.

Separate Chrome accounts have nothing to do with this, because DPAPI is linked to the Windows user only.

Therefore, the solution is to have any other people on the computer use their own Windows accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Chrome does not support a master password for its built-in password manager / storage. This means that any person who is logged in to your user account on your computer can view your Chrome passwords in plain text, and they won't even need WebBrowserPassView.

> There’s no master password, no security, not even a prompt that “these passwords are visible”. Visit `chrome://settings/passwords` in Chrome if you don’t believe me.

Source: [Chrome’s insane password security strategy](http://blog.elliottkember.com/chromes-insane-password-security-strategy) (more details on Chrome's password storing mechanism on this blog article)

Use a third-party password manager which offers support for a master password such as KeePass or LastPass to get around this issue. In case you're willing to use another browser instead, Firefox offers support for a master password, making its passwords not viewable in WebBrowserPassView.